# Should models be created for lookup tables in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have few lookup tables which are listed below. As of my understanding we need a Model for each database table, but does this also apply to lookup / mapping tables? what is the best practice used while creating models? Below is a sample of my lookup tables...

```
Transaction     Customer     Transaction_Lookup       
id              Id           transection_id
date            name         customer_id
active          active
```

I have created models corresponding to Transaction and Customer tables, do I need to create a corresponding model for Transaction_Lookup as well?

Also I am using Data Mapper pattern which means I will also have to create a Mapper class for each model...

Thanks for your help in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One remark I would make is to not think of models as corresponding one-to-one with tables.  That can be very limiting in your OOP design.  That said it is true often your models will align to a single table.  Look-up tables being an obvious scenario where this is true.

As for needing a concrete model for each lookup table...  I would consider writing a generic Model that could be used for all objects corresponding to 'lookup' tables.  You could then use that generic class, or write it as an abstract and extend it and create named concrete classes.  The amount of unique code needed there could be very limited, leveraging what you already have on the parent class.  If you wanted a look up table specific abstract you could abstract the fields *key(id)*, *value*, *friendly name*, *active?* and map the corresponding fields on the tables to those generic properties.  Really a number of ways to go about that, hope I explained it well.

I typically write two styles of mappers, ones that are essentially table row gateways like Zend_Db_Table and another that is more custom, where perhaps I use a stored procedure or complex Zend_Db_selects joining off multiple tables.  Using the table row gateway style mappers I usually just need to specify a table name, adapter, and mapped object for the mapper to work with.  On the custom mappers I usually need to write more of the implementation code from scratch on a case by case.

I like this approach of using a [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).  Can be both convenient and powerful.

Comment: Cool.  I found this to be a useful link on some of these subjects specific to ZF.  http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0